# MicrosemiTools and C++

Tags: actel, softconsole, smartfusion

I've been trying to work with the Microsemi SmartFusion FPGA/MCU SOC boards and their "free" toolchain that includes an Eclipse-based "SoftConsole" IDE that appears to be based on the GNU C/C++ compiler chain.  The [Actel website claims](http://www.actel.com/products/software/softconsole/) the compiler supports C and C++ but the [FAQ says [warning: pdf]](http://www.actel.com/documents/softconsole_FAQ.pdf) C++ projects are not supported.  Have any of you succeeded in creating simple C++ classes/objects with the tools?

Comment: I would ask your Actel FAE or their support email.

Comment: I sent an email late yesterday and will post the response as soon as I have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friendly Microsemi FAE has shared that SoftConsole v3.4 should support C++ now.

Answer (score 3):

We have been successfully running C++ code on SmartFusion under uClinux using the GNU toolchain from CodeSourcery.

Further details are [here](http://www.emcraft.com).

Comment: That's a great tip!  I'm running bare-metal though. No OS'es for me.